# Am I still Fleishig? When did we eat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, safek

I'm sure this happens many times in a Jewish home on Shabbos: It's Shalosh Seudos time and there's dairy to eat, except no one remembers exactly what time the Shabbos meal took place.

So, my question is, how do we deal with a Safek (doubt) when it comes to waiting between meat and dairy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is discussed in [Darkei Teshuva (89:5)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40536&st=&pgnum=275). He brings an authority that says one may not eat until he is sure 6 hours have passed (or whatever one's customary waiting time may be), and that the general rule of ספק דרבנן לקולא does not apply here. He then brings several others who disagree and believe that the rule does apply here and one may eat dairy if he is in doubt if sufficient time has passed.

Comment: Besides the _Darche T'shuva_ and the authorities he quotes, I have in my notes that Rabbi _Akiva_ Eiger and the _P'ri M'gadim_ are lenient about this, for the same reason as the _Darche T'shuva_, q.v. No citation, though, I'm afraid. In any event, as always, for practical guidance, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Comment: Don't we say in many cases that Safek DeRabbanan LeKulah doesn't apply to Minhagim - or at least that Minhagim are more Ḥamur than DeRabbanans? Sorry, I can't think of other examples offhand; it just seems to be sticking out in my mind for some reason.

Comment: @SethJ I think I read in Kaf HaHaim that this doesn't count as "safek deraban lekula" here.